# Kill all process by name running over one hour via terminal

Tags: command-line, text-processing, process, ps

I'm currently tying to kill all the process with the name `/ebook-convert/` in them that are running over an hour.

When I try this command, I get that the process don't exist.

```
kill $(ps -eo pid,etimes,args | awk '/ebook-convert/ { if ($2 > 3600) print $2 }')
```

I'm unsure if either my awk is wrong or if the regex to find the `ebook-convert` command is wrong.

Comment: I would use 'killall -r ebook'  if no other processes have 'ebook' in their name. you can also get the pid from 'kill -9 $(pidof pan)' for example. see https://linuxize.com/post/kill-command-in-linux/ for firefox example

Comment: Note it would be much easier if instead of sniping the processes from outside, your `ebook-convert` process was started under control of some tool that would kill it after an hour. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/5161193/42610 for some tools for doing so.

Comment: think `pkill -O 3600 ebook-convert` will do the same

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured it out, on my print column `print $2`, I was printing the time, not the process id, so by changing that to `print $1` it works. ie,

```
kill $(ps -eo pid,etimes,args | awk '/ebook-convert/ { if ($2 > 3600) print $1 }')
```